# How can I make a variable work in more that one class? (Java)

Tags: java, variables

I am working on a java code to calculate the cost of a pizza but my variables do not work in other classes. I'm getting an error called "cannot find symbols".

This is my code so far.

```
class PizzaCost {

   public static void main (String []args){      
   }    
}

class pizza {

  int smallPizza = 4;      
  int mediumPizza = 6;     
  int largePizza = 12;

}


class rules {

  double laborCost = 0.75;     
  double rentCost = 1.00;      
  double materialsCost = 0.05; //per diameter

}


class costCalculator {     

  double smallPizzaCost = (smallPizza*materialsCost) + rentCost + laborCost;      
  double mediumPizzaCost = (mediumPizza*materialsCost) + rentCost + laborCost;      
  double largePizzaCost = (largePizza*materialsCost) + rentCost + laborCost;

}
```

Comment: define your variables as public, or better yet, use accessors and mutators

Comment: @OrelEraki Technically, members with no access modifier have "default" access (commonly referred to as "package private") which is not the same as `private`.

Comment: I hate to say this, but the entire program has gotten so far off on the wrong path that fixing your error message isn't going to help.  I agree with the suggestion to study the [tutorial on Object Oriented basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put static like this

```
public static int smallPizza = 4
```

and reference with

```
pizza.smallPizza
```

or just create pizza object like
    pizza p = new pizza();

and reference with.
    p.smallPizza